# Circuit transform

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current

[image]
Given circuit (a), and I want to find V_out as a function of V_in. R1, R2, V_B is constant.

Since V_out = I*R_2, I need to find the current flowing int the circuit(a).

Is it OK to change the circuit(a) to circuit(b) to find the current?

I mean, is I_(a) same as I_(b) = (V_in + V_B) / (R_1 + R_2) ?

Comment: Where is Vin and Vout in (b)?

Comment: Same V_in as (a), the left part of circuit.
But I think I can't indicate V_out in (b). I want to use circuit(b) just to find the current of (a).

Comment: Sorry, "left part of the circuit" is no good. Please draw the schematic will all information. We don't like to have vital pieces of information sprinkled in the comments. If you have zero current going in our our from the node Vout and you don't care about the value, you can flip them if that helps you to calculate the current in the circuit.

Comment: I edited it. Thank you!

Comment: Components in series have the same current through them. Why is a transformation required?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know mathematically what you are doing you can change any circuit to any other circuit and fortunately in your circuit this method works (due to simplicity of problem)

But for complex circuits avoid these methods for analysis and use some basic theorems like thevenin and superposition to solve a complex circuits